# Code not working with post name Permalink Settings Help

Tags: plugins

I'm writing a simple affiliate plugin that does the following:

1. Takes the GET var of affid
2. Sets a cookie

My problem is that it only works when I have the permalinks set to plain which is ?page_id=342 when I set it to post name I get 404 error and the cookie is not set. Whats wrong with the code?

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'affiliate_redirect');
function affiliate_redirect() {
$varname = 'affid';
$weeks = '4';
if( isset($_GET[$varname]) && '' != $_GET[$varname] ) {
setcookie('wp_affiliate', $_GET[$varname], time()+648000*$weeks, '/');
$pageURL = 'http';
if ( isset( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] ) && strtolower( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] ) ==        "on" ) {
$pageURL .= "s";
}
$pageURL .= "://";
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
$pageURL .=     $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]    ;
} else {
$pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
$url = preg_replace('/([?&])'.$varname.'=[^&]+(&|$)/','$1',$pageURL);
$last = $url[strlen($url)-1];
if ($last == '?') {
$url = substr_replace($url ,"",-1);
}
wp_redirect($url);
exit;
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting a 404, because when I run your code with permalinks = "Post name" it runs fine.

However, I would suggest you use [remove_query_arg()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_query_arg/) instead of all the machinations you're doing to produce the URL to redirect to.  That is, you can simplify your code down to:

```
function
affiliate_redirect ()
{
    $varname = 'affid' ;
    $weeks = '4' ;
    if (isset ($_GET[$varname]) && '' != $_GET[$varname]) {
        setcookie ('wp_affiliate', $_GET[$varname], time () + 648000 * $weeks, '/') ;

        $url = remove_query_arg ($varname) ;
        wp_redirect ($url) ;

        exit ;
        }

    return ;
}
```

Try that and see if it doesn't fix your 404 problem.

Comment: Still get a 404 my url structure is https://domain.com/about/affid=testvar even if I go to the root of the Domain I still get a 404 https://domain.com/affid=testvar

Comment: that explains it: you should be hitting `domain.com/about/?affid=testvar` (note the `?` before `affid=testvar`).  When using "plain" permalinks, WP is already adding the '?' and you're probably just appending `&affid=testvar`, right?

Comment: yes you are right it is working now. Is there any way to make it work without the ?

Comment: not easily :-( First, you'd have to modify your .htaccess to make sure that `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` was set (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497404/php-serverpath-info-and-apache-mod-rewrite) for more info).  Then you'd have to  muck with the WP [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API), to strip the `PATH_INFO` part of the URL (so that it doesn't try to find a page/post with that slug), then you'd have to parse `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` instead of reading `$_GET`.  If you **need** URLs of that form, I suggest you ask _another_ question as to how to do that.

Comment: Much appreciate your help Paul I will just stick with your first solution.